# Claptrap in his own mind?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

I'm curious how Claptastic Voyage explains entering Claptrap's mind if you're playing as Claptrap? Is it a different Claptrap?

Comment: I don't think it explains going into Claptrap's own mind. I know it's not a different Claptrap because the story goes through the events that Claptrap has seen and flushes out some of the story points.

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't lampshade it in any of Claptrap's dialogue. That would be par for the course for the dev's of this series.